Unable to call protected endpoints when sending valid session cookie spring boot
I have an application that is running React Remix on the front end. It is authenticating, and creating session cookies to be used to validate the user. This session cookie is included in the http requests.
We also have a Java spring boot backend that we want to access and use this same session cookie to protect certain endpoints. I have created a filter to check the existence of the cookie, if its there then we want to consider the user authenticated, then we can pass the request to the desired endpoint.
Based on the logs in the filter, it is finding the cookie and finishing error free. But then remix is getting 401 errors and my logs in the endpoint are not reached indicating that the filter never passed on the request.
Can some one help? Is there some other filtering that spring security will do that i need to bypass some how?
Here is my filter and secuirty config:
package com.example.surfspotsapi.config;

import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

public class SessionCookieFilter implements Filter {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionCookieFilter.class);

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    logger.info("Entering SessionCookieFilter for request: {}", httpRequest.getRequestURI());

    Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
    boolean sessionCookieExists = false;

    if (cookies != null) {
      for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if ("session".equals(cookie.getName())) {
          sessionCookieExists = true;
          logger.info("Session cookie found for request: {}", httpRequest.getRequestURI());
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (sessionCookieExists) {
      PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authToken = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken("preAuthenticatedUser",
          null, null);
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);

      logger.info("Pre-authenticated token set for request: {}", httpRequest.getRequestURI());
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
      logger.warn("Session cookie missing, blocking request: {}", httpRequest.getRequestURI());
      httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
  }
}



package com.lovettj.surfspotsapi.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SessionCookieFilter sessionCookieFilter() {
    return new SessionCookieFilter();
  }

  @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) // Disable CSRF for API usage
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/api/user/login", "/api/user/register",
                    "/api/user/profile", "/api/continents/**",
                    "/api/countries/**", "/api/regions/**",
                    "/api/surf-spots/**")
                .permitAll() // Public endpoints
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // Protect other endpoints
            )
            .addFilterBefore(sessionCookieFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}```

